How to Scrape NBA stats page using rvest
The page I am interested in scraping is here: https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shots-general?GeneralRange=Pullups&SeasonType=Regular+Season
I have the following code which I have tried running
library(httr2)

req_url <- "https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shots-general?GeneralRange=Pullups&SeasonType=Regular+Season"

json <- 
  request(req_url) |>
  req_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36") |>
  req_headers(
    Accept = "*/*",
    Origin = "https://www.nba.com",
    Referer = "https://www.nba.com/",
  ) |> 
  req_perform() |>
  resp_body_json() 

hdr <- json$resultSets$headers

# build column names from 2-level header structure
clean_names <- 
  c(
    rep("", hdr[[1]]$columnsToSkip), 
    rep(unlist(hdr[[1]]$columnNames), each = 3)
  ) |>
  paste(unlist(hdr[[2]]$columnNames)) |>
  janitor::make_clean_names()
clean_names


# make each list in a `rowSet` a named list, 
# this allows us to use dplyr::bind_rows() to create a tibble
data <- json$resultSets$rowSet |>
  lapply(setNames, clean_names) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()

When I run this I get the following error
Error in `resp_body_json()`:
! Unexpected content type "text/html".
• Expecting type "application/json" or suffix "json".

Could someone point me to what the req_url variable should be please

The URL you're probing returns HTML. If you want to use a JSON response, as in your current code, you'll need to search the site for where (if at all) they provide such a service ("API" and "JSON" are useful keywords). If they don't, you can try extracting the table(s) from the HTML response, which gets repeatedly asked and answered here.

resp_body_json only works if the server actually returns a JSON file. It cannot transform the result into JSON if it's in some other format. In this case, the website is returning regular HTML.

There is an API. You can make this even easier on yourself... there's an R package for that...check it out.

@I_O what would the code look like for returning HTML please?

For the context, OP was trying to modify a solution suggested for  Webscraping NBA.com


Could someone point me to what the req_url variable should be please

For this approach you'd first need to figure out the actual API call that is made by your web browser when it fetches data for the table. Common aproach is to extract this interactively through the Network tab of browser's developer tools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome-based browsers in Windows). Make sure DevTools is open when you load or refresh the page to capture all request. To reduce number of candidate calls from tens or hundreds to few, you can start by defining a filter and/or going through a search (Ctrl+f when Network tab is active), looking for for some specific phrase or value from the target table is usually much faster than scrolling through a full list of requests:

Just be aware that rendered values might not be in the same format as delivered content (e.g. 0.287000 from JSON response vs formatted 28.7 (%) in rendered table). You can get API url through request's context menu or Headers pane.
And note that different API endpoints might or might not share the same response structure, meaning that you are not guaranteed to get it working by just plugging in a different API request while not modifying JSON parsing suggested in some previous answer.

As an alternative, you might try rvest::read_html_live(). It first renders requested page (incl. dynamic content, e.g.  Javascript-rendered tables) in a headless browsers, allows you to interact with a live browser session and to work with the same Javascript-modified DOM-tree you'd see in DevTools object inspector of your desktop browser:
library(rvest)

url_ <- "https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shots-general?GeneralRange=Pullups&SeasonType=Regular+Season" 
read_html_live(url_) |>
  html_element("table.Crom_table__p1iZz") |> 
  html_table() 
#> # A tibble: 31 × 19
#>    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    `Field Goals` `Field Goals` `Field Goals`
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
#>  1 TEAM  GP    G     Freq% FGM   FGA   FG%           eFG%          2FG Freq%    
#>  2 Milw… 82    82    28.7  10.3  26.3  39.3          46.2          16.3         
#>  3 Los … 81    81    27.0  10.0  24.9  40.2          47.7          15.6         
#>  4 Bost… 81    81    26.9  9.4   24.6  38.0          45.5          14.4         
#>  5 Minn… 82    82    27.4  8.7   23.7  36.8          42.5          17.1         
#>  6 Dall… 81    81    26.2  9.2   23.6  38.9          45.9          15.2         
#>  7 San … 81    81    25.5  9.7   23.6  41.1          48.3          15.0         
#>  8 Hous… 82    82    26.8  9.3   23.6  39.6          47.4          14.5         
#>  9 Orla… 82    82    27.8  9.1   23.3  39.0          46.8          15.5         
#> 10 Broo… 79    79    26.4  9.1   23.3  39.1          46.9          14.2         
#> # ℹ 21 more rows
#> # ℹ 10 more variables: `Field Goals` <chr>, `Field Goals` <chr>,
#> #   `2 Point Field Goals` <chr>, `2 Point Field Goals` <chr>,
#> #   `2 Point Field Goals` <chr>, `2 Point Field Goals` <chr>,
#> #   `3 Point Field Goals` <chr>, `3 Point Field Goals` <chr>,
#> #   `3 Point Field Goals` <chr>, `3 Point Field Goals` <chr>

Created on 2024-09-18 with reprex v2.1.1

Appolgoes as I do my coding in Python and its been about 5 years since I touched R. But converting my python solution to R is below.
As mentioned, there is an API to access this data and returns in json. The key for nba site is you need the referrer in the headers.
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

# Base URL
base_url <- "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashoppptshot"

# Define the query parameters
params <- list(
    "Conference" = "",
    "DateFrom" = "",
    "DateTo" = "",
    "Division" = "",
    "GameSegment" = "",
    "GeneralRange" = "Pullups",
    "LastNGames" = "0",
    "LeagueID" = "00",
    "Location" = "",
    "Month" = "0",
    "OpponentTeamID" = "0",
    "Outcome" = "",
    "PORound" = "0",
    "PerMode" = "PerGame",
    "Period" = "0",
    "PlayerExperience" = "",
    "PlayerPosition" = "",
    "Season" = "2023-24",
    "SeasonSegment" = "",
    "SeasonType" = "Regular Season",
    "TeamID" = "0",
    "VsConference" = "",
    "VsDivision" = ""
)

# Headers required by the NBA stats API
headers <- c(
    "User-Agent" = paste(
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)",
        "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)",
        "Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    ),
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Accept" = "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache",
    "Connection" = "keep-alive",
    "Host" = "stats.nba.com",
    "Origin" = "https://www.nba.com",
    "Pragma" = "no-cache",
    "Referer" = "https://www.nba.com/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest" = "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode" = "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site" = "same-site",
    "x-nba-stats-origin" = "stats",
    "x-nba-stats-token" = "true"
)

# Make the GET request
response <- GET(url = base_url, add_headers(.headers = headers), query = params, timeout(10))

# Check if the request was successful
if (response$status_code != 200) {
    print(paste("Request failed with status code", response$status_code))
    print(content(response, as = "text"))
} else {
    # Parse the JSON response
    json_data <- content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
    json_data <- fromJSON(json_data)
    
    # Extract headers and row data
    result_sets <- json_data$resultSets[[1]]
    column_headers <- result_sets$headers
    row_data <- result_sets$rowSet
    
    # Create a DataFrame from the row data and column headers
    df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, row_data), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    names(df) <- column_headers
    
    # Clean column names: convert to lowercase and replace spaces with underscores
    df <- df %>%
        clean_names()
    
    # Display the DataFrame
    print(head(df))
}


Thank you for doing this. For some reason the
"  # Extract headers and row data
result_sets <- json_data$resultSets[[1]]
column_headers <- result_sets$headers
row_data <- result_sets$rowSet"
Part didnt work correctly as it gave me the following error
Error in result_sets$headers : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
But I was able to make minor modifications to your code to get what I needed.
Thanks again!!

ya like I said - been a few years since I used R - and don't have it installed on my system to test it. Feel free to edit my response with the fixes you made.

yea thanks so much! one last question for my own understanding. How did you work out what base_url (https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashoppptshot) should be? I am trying to scrape another table (https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/isolation) which looks to be in a different format to the table you helped me with

When you are on the site, right click and "Inspect" (shft-ctrl-i). It'll open a side tab - you'll need to refresh the page so that the info will populate. Then look at the XHR tab to search there for the data responses that get the data you want. When you click on the links, you should see those requests being made in the XHR tab there too. Then you can look at the Headers to see what the url is that makes that data request

Just looking at that now - it doesn't appear that data actually comes from the api. That one, is a little different. You can get it from the html, and whitin the html is a <script> tag with the json - you'd have to parse the html and pull out that json to convert it
